# Django application does not create tables

Tags: python, django, wsgi

So, I have created a django app here: http://fpaste.org/bkFf/ without using django-admin.

I want the model that I have created in models.py (http://fpaste.org/i1Vd/) to automatically create the table in the database, as specified in settings.py (http://fpaste.org/GBz0/).

I run the command django-admin syncdb --settings=settings.py, which gives me the following: http://fpaste.org/tgvK/ - but no tables are created (because it should say created table X after Creating tables....)

As I didn't create it using django-admin.py, I have no 'project' - so I have no application to add to an INSTALLED_APPS variable of settings.py.

Ultimately, my question it - how can I get my models to initialise the tables in the database, without needing to use django-admin (other than using the syncdb flag).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have no 'project' - so I have no application to add to an INSTALLED_APPS

This makes no sense at all. Projects have nothing to do with INSTALLED_APPS. You have a settings.py, and you have a models.py. Put the name of the module containing models.py into INSTALLED_APPS, and things will work.

Comment: My thought was that you create a project (via django-admin startproject myproject) and create an app within the project. This 'app' containing manage.py etc is what would need to be added to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: The *project* contains manage.py, settings.py, etc. The *app* does not. The *app* is where models.py, views.py, admin.py, etc. go. Simply, projects have many apps but apps have one project.

Comment: After reworking my project to the following layout: http://fpaste.org/XPik/ and adding FirstService to my INSTALLED_APPS variable, I ran syncdb again, still with no luck. FirstService is now the module (or application) that contains models.py isn't it?